# Value 'Future' on 'date' parameter of event_search service also returns old events

Tags: eventbrite

I'm consuming the event_search service, thereby passing the 'keywords' parameter and the 'date' parameter. As I'm only interested in future events, for the 'date' parameter, I pass the value 'future'. So the URL looks like follows:

http://www.eventbrite.com/event_search?app_key=&keywords=&date=future

I found out that I get the same events, as when I call the service without the 'date=future' parameter, namely including the past events. I did not work with the other values of the 'date' parameter.

Did I run into a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The /event_search method doesn't support "date=future", but the default return should only be future events.

If you're receiving events that have both an "start_date" **and** "end_date" in the past, then you've encountered a bug.

I recently did some testing, and could not reproduce. So, hopefully you're no longer seeing this issue.